# Allow only one user to access a page at a time in struts application

Tags: multithreading, struts2, singleton

Having an huge customers profile page  if two or more users start using same page and start editing big change will happen in my database so planing to implement Threads concept where only one user can use that customer page

i'm aware about threads concept but confused how to implement it
 hope i need to use Singleton class  as well

Any suggestion or Logic's will be helpful

I'm using Struts,Hibernate frame work

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: sorry if i'm wrong : want to know how to implement above things let me know if u need more info

Comment: Do you have any code illustrating your attempt?

Comment: My recommendation is to give it a try on your own, there's plenty of great resources online - google is your friend. Come back, and even if your solution doesn't work, we can help debug it and continue pointing you in the right direction. This way we can help you learn, but you'll still be doing the learning ;)

Comment: thanks will get back to you :-)

Comment: So what is the exact problem you have? How big is a *big change*?

Answer (score 0):

You may use application context to store a flag variable. Action will use its value to allow only one simultaneous execution.

```
public class TestAction extends ActionSupport implements ApplicationAware {
    private static final String APP_BUSY_KEY = "APP_BUSY";
    Map<String, Object> map;

    @Override
    public void setApplication(Map<String, Object> map) {
        this.map = map;
    }

    @Override
    public String execute() throws Exception {
        if (map.containsKey(APP_BUSY_KEY)) {
            return ERROR;
        } else {
            map.put(APP_BUSY_KEY, "1");
            try {
                // action logic here
            } finally {
                map.remove(APP_BUSY_KEY);
            }
            return SUCCESS;
        }
    }
}
```

If you plan to implement similar logic for two requests (lock after displaying values and release lock after submitting new values) then logic will be more complex and you will also need to handle lock release after timeout.